# PWA редирект без окна браузера

Tags: домен, site, app, pwa, domain

Подскажите как решить проблему, у меня очень важная задача

Есть домен example.com, он привязан к tilda, пусть даже будет подомен app.example.com который привязан к beget-у....
Мне нужно, чтобы через app.example.com устанавливалось pwa, и после этого, когда его открывают, там был сайт не app.example.com а example.com и при этом, без окна браузера.

пробовал следующие методы:

meta name refresh и в js window.open

meta name refresh - работает но окно браузера появляется

window.open вообще не работает с свойством _blank или любым другим

iframe - тоже не вариант, так как на сайте в тильде есть личный кабинет, который при перезапуске pwa забывает данные входа.

какие есть варианты?